# Logger output is not working in UWP C++ Unit Testing Project, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp

In Visual Studio 2022, in a Universal Windows solution, the **Logger** functionality is broken in the UWP C++/CX Unit test app project--no output can be found either in the (Test Detail) Summary window or the output window (particularly, not to be found under 'tests').

The code that should work in the new project is simply,

```
Logger::WriteMessage("**My Testing Message**");
```

The documents for using Logger are here, as the documentation for UWP unit testing is tailored for C# and doesn't use Logger:
[Microsoft Documentation on the Visual Studio C++ unit test framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference)

I've looked for alternatively named output windows, under View>Other windows>, but didn't find where the Logger is going, if anywhere. I checked for Test Explorer options with the keywords log, and output. I enabled logging, and sent the log to Cross Platform Logging, but this stayed empty through unit test runs.

The unit test project gives green lights in Test Explorer, and Assert functionality works. I created a second UWP unit test app project, and as a minimum conditions test placed the Logger::WriteMessage line in Test Method 1, which built fine, and was discovered by Test explorer, but again no Logger output was to be found.

[image: Test Explorer Image]

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Ian Boyd for the .runsettings tip, which certainly reveals more functionality. Looking at the log file in TestResults revealed no Logger output however--it was not quite a facsimile of the Test Detail Summary information for each test (it posted an exact test duration, instead of "<1ms").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Use 0 for maximum process-level parallelization. This does not force parallelization within the test DLL (on the thread-level). You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Run tests in parallel". Unchecked = 1 (only 1), checked = 0 (max). -->
<MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
<!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
<ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

<!-- Omit the whole tag for auto-detection. -->
<!-- [x86] or x64, ARM, ARM64, s390x  -->
<!-- You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects" -->
<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>

<!-- Any TargetFramework moniker or omit the whole tag for auto-detection. -->
<!-- net48, [net40], net6.0, net5.0, netcoreapp3.1, uap10.0 etc. <TargetFrameworkVersion></TargetFrameworkVersion>-->


<!-- Path to Test Adapters %SystemDrive%\Temp\foo;%SystemDrive%\Temp\bar <TestAdaptersPaths></TestAdaptersPaths>-->


<!-- TestCaseFilter expression <TestCaseFilter>(TestCategory != Integration) &amp; (TestCategory != UnfinishedFeature)</TestCaseFilter>-->


<!-- TestSessionTimeout was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
<!-- Specify timeout in milliseconds. A valid value should be greater than 0 -->
<TestSessionTimeout>10000</TestSessionTimeout>

<!-- true or false -->
<!-- Value that specifies the exit code when no tests are discovered -->
<TreatNoTestsAsError>true</TreatNoTestsAsError>
</RunConfiguration>

<!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
<DataCollectionRunSettings>
<DataCollectors>
  <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    <Configuration>
      <CodeCoverage>
        <ModulePaths>
          <Exclude>
            <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
          </Exclude>
        </ModulePaths>

        <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
                      <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
               <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

      </CodeCoverage>
    </Configuration>
  </DataCollector>

  <!-- Configuration for blame data collector -->
  <DataCollector friendlyName="blame" enabled="false">
  </DataCollector>

</DataCollectors>
</DataCollectionRunSettings>

<!-- Parameters used by tests at run time -->
<TestRunParameters>
<Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
<Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="admin" />
<Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="" />
</TestRunParameters>

<!-- Configuration for loggers -->
<LoggerRunSettings>
<Loggers>
  <Logger friendlyName="console" enabled="True">
    <Configuration>
        <Verbosity>verbose</Verbosity>
    </Configuration>
  </Logger>
  <Logger friendlyName="trx" enabled="True">
    <Configuration>
      <LogFileName>foo.trx</LogFileName>
    </Configuration>
  </Logger>
  <Logger friendlyName="html" enabled="True">
    <Configuration>
      <LogFileName>foo.html</LogFileName>
    </Configuration>
  </Logger>
  <Logger friendlyName="blame" enabled="True" />
</Loggers>
     </LoggerRunSettings>

     <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->

     
   </RunSettings>
```

Comment: I think people are going to need to see your `.runsettings` xml file that contains the logger configuration information.

Comment: According to the documentation, *Runsettings files are optional. If you don't require any special configuration, you don't need a .runsettings file.*